# Creating Path from edges of the Bitmap android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view

Is there any way by which I can create a **android.graphics.Path** from edges of the **Bitmap**?
Suppose I have a **hollow hexagon**, then how can I create a path which will follow the edges of it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do this as a path is part of vector graphics whereas a bitmap is composed of independent pixels. You could create an algorithm that does this, but it would be complex and would never be a 100% sure thing.

The best thing you could do is either start with a vector graphic in the first place (such as SVG), or give up on your dream of scalable graphics.

I'm sorry to disappoint you, but I tried creating a pseudo-code vector finder in here, and even a simple one is too complex to write on the fly.